# Matlabcontrol in Java

Tags: java, matlab

I was working on the following program from https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough. I wish to call Matlab function in Java using Matlab control. I imported matlabcontrol in the program.
First 2 sample programs worked fine for me.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
{
    //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
    MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
    MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

    //Create a 4x3x2 array filled with random values
    proxy.eval("array = randn(4,3,2)");

    //Print a value of the array into the MATLAB Command Window
    proxy.eval("disp(['entry: ' num2str(array(3, 2, 1))])");

    //Get the array from MATLAB
    MatlabTypeConverter processor = new MatlabTypeConverter(proxy);
    MatlabNumericArray array = processor.getNumericArray("array");

    //Print out the same entry, using Java's 0-based indexing
    System.out.println("entry: " + array.getRealValue(2, 1, 0));

    //Convert to a Java array and print the same value again    
    double[][][] javaArray = array.getRealArray3D();
    System.out.println("entry: " + javaArray[2][1][0]);

    //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
    proxy.disconnect();
}
```

---

When I run this program on Windows, Java gives me the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>javac Helloworld3.java
Helloworld3.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MatlabTypeConverter
location: class Helloworld3
    MatlabTypeConverter processor = new MatlabTypeConverter(proxy);
    ^
Helloworld3.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MatlabTypeConverter
location: class Helloworld3
    MatlabTypeConverter processor = new MatlabTypeConverter(proxy);
                                        ^
Helloworld3.java:62: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MatlabNumericArray
location: class Helloworld3
    MatlabNumericArray array = processor.getNumericArray("array");
    ^
3 errors
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Some of these are generic Java issues. For example, in `javac matlabcontrol-4.1. 0.jar Helloworld2.java` is looks like you forgot the `-cp` flag. Also, like the compiler says, if `HelloWorld2` is a public class, it needs a file matching its name. Finally, if seems odd to be compiling this stuff in the bin of the JDK folder. It might get overridden if you choose to update.

Comment: Just curious, how did you set it up to be able to use matlab control? I m testing things out and setting up environment variables PATH, but i still cant launch Matlab from Java for some reason @user24094

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I got the answer. We need to import a file as:

```
import matlabcontrol.extensions.MatlabTypeConverter;
```

Now, it is working fine!